# Using a delegate twice inside of a unit test

Tags: delegates, nunit

I have some unit tests where I’m using the DoesNotThrow feature of Nunit.  Up until recently, I wasn’t concerned w/ the actual response coming back.  However, I recently needed to add a check for the count on my result set.  I now have a redundant call in my code.  Can I clean this up and make use of the delegate within my second Assert call?

```
Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => new GetMyCollection.GetCollection(request));

var response = new GetMyCollection().GetCollection(request);
Assert.Greater(response.MyCount, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get rid of the first line entirely:

```
var response = new GetMyCollection().GetCollection(request);
Assert.Greater(response.MyCount, 0);
```

If `new GetMyCollection().GetCollection(request)` throws an exception, that will make the test fail anyway.

`Assert.DoesNotThrow` is relatively pointless, IMO - I would only usually use it to contrast with some `Assert.Throws` calls.